# Extract Text from HTML Python (BeautifulSoup, RE, Other Option?)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am familiar with BeautifulSoup and Regular Expressions as a means of extracting text from HTML but not as familiar with others, such as ElementTree, Minidom, etc.

My question is fairly straightforward. Given the HTML snippet below, which library is best for extracting the text below? The text being the integer.

```
<td class="tl-cell tl-popularity" data-tooltip="7,944,796" data-tooltip-instant="">
<div class="pop-meter">
<div class="pop-meter-background"></div>
<div class="pop-meter-overlay" style="width: 55%"></div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: well `re` is definitely not a good option, a trivial change to the  html and your regex can break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) it is fairly straight-forward:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<td class="tl-cell tl-popularity" data-tooltip="7,944,796" data-tooltip-instant="">
<div class="pop-meter">
<div class="pop-meter-background"></div>
<div class="pop-meter-overlay" style="width: 55%"></div>
</div>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.td['data-tooltip'])
```

If you have multiple `td` elements and you need to extract the `data-tooltip` from each one:

```
for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-tooltip': True}):
    print(td['data-tooltip'])
```

Comment: The question is surely opinion-based, and while this solution is "beautiful" you fail to point out why it *is best*. ;-) +1